# Why are mails from my domain going to spam?

Tags: gmail

Emails get stuck in spam.

Spamfilter
Blocking lists

Mails from my domain get stuck in spam sometimes, but it's unpredictable when so I can't really recreate the issue. I checked isnotspam.com and blacklists, but those results are positive. Please help me

Thanks in advance

Oli

Answer (score 0):

Spam filters are always changing, but there are some things you can do to avoid your emails getting flagged. Since you said you've checked the blacklists already, verify your content. If your emails have spammy content, like using telemarketer-esque language, all caps, lots of exclamation points, etc., they may be getting flagged as spam.

There's more info here: https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-marketing/how-email-spam-tests-work-and-what-you-can-do-to-pass-them

You can also look into your DomainKeys Identified Mail (DKIM), Sender Policy Framework (SPF), and DMARC (Domain-based Message Authentication).